# How to get distinct numbers in window?

Tags: python

You are given an array of N integers, A<sup>1</sup>, A<sup>2</sup>, ... A<sup>N</sup> and an integer B. Return the of count of distinct numbers in all windows of size B.

- `A = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3]`
- `B = 3`
- Output =  `[2, 3, 3, 2]`

`A=[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3]` and `B = 3`. All windows of size `B`, output is:

```
 [1, 2, 1]
 [2, 1, 3]
 [1, 3, 4]
 [3, 4, 3]
 So, we return an array [2, 3, 3, 2].
```

Code is below

```
result = [len(set(A[i:i+B])) for i in range(len(A)-B+1)]
```

Error:

I got the correct output, but am getting time limit exceed error because it's unnecessary to check every count in window. Could I add every number from right and remove from left? How to do implement this?

Comment: Use a single `dict` or `Counter` to update a sliding window instead of creating a new `set` for each section.

Comment: @Socowi can you put psedo code

Comment: It is unlikely that adding and removing numbers like you want to do would be faster than taking a different slice.

Comment: How to you **know** what is causing the time limit to be exceed?

Comment: @martineau For `B=3` that might be the case. I assumed OP's problem might occur for larger `B`. For something like `B=1000` my suggestion should be tremendously faster, don't you think so? Either way, your suggestion to identify the bottleneck first makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script processes each entry `B` times. The larger `B` becomes, the less efficient your script is.

If you use a sliding window it is sufficient to process each entry twice:

```
from collections import Counter    
def uniqueNumbersInWindow(A, B): 
    result = []
    slidingWindow = Counter(A[0:B])
    result.append(len(slidingWindow))
    for remove, add in zip(A, A[B:]):
        slidingWindow[remove] -= 1
        if (slidingWindow[remove] == 0):
             del slidingWindow[remove]
        slidingWindow[add] += 1
        result.append(len(slidingWindow))
    return result
```

#### Benchmark

I benchmarked this and [achy97's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69245153/6770384) against your naive solution:

```
len_a = 10_000_000
same = [7] * len_a
rand = random.choices(range(1000), k=len_a)
samples = 3
for f in ['socowi', 'achy97', 'op']:
    for b in [3, 1000]:
        for a in ['same', 'rand']:
            t = timeit.timeit(
                    f'{f}({a},{b})',
                    number=samples,
                    globals=globals()
                ) / samples
            print(f'| {f} | {a} | {b} | {t:.2f}s |')
```

| Solution | A | B | Avg. Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| socowi | same | 3 | 4.17s |
| socowi | rand | 3 | 8.51s |
| socowi | same | 1000 | 4.63s |
| socowi | rand | 1000 | 7.20s |
| achy97 | same | 3 | 4.48s |
| achy97 | rand | 3 | 6.32s |
| achy97 | same | 1000 | 4.68s |
| achy97 | rand | 1000 | 6.11s |
| op | same | 3 | 2.68s |
| op | rand | 3 | 2.92s |
| op | same | 1000 | 101.27s |
| op | rand | 1000 | 186.67s |

The results show, that the runtime of sliding window solutions is independent of `B`.

Comment: zip(A, A[B:]) can you comment the code

Comment: `for remove, add in zip(A, A[B:])` is a shorthand for `for i in range(len(A)-B): remove=A[i]; add=A[i+B];`.

Answer (score 1):

so The approach is called Sliding window.
You maintain a hashmap - which contains the counts of first B digits, then you have to move forward by 1 digit, and modify the hashmap, so in this way you can easily get the non-zero counts of keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def solve(A, B):
    dic=defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    ls=[]

    for i in range(B):
        dic[A[i]]+=1
    ls.append(len(dic.keys()))
    
    for i in range(1, len(A)-B+1):
        #delete elimitating char count
        dic[A[i-1]]-=1

        #take prev count as reference to avoid duplicate counting
        s=ls[-1]

        #if eliminating char freq is 0, delete the count
        if dic[A[i-1]]==0 and B>1:
            s-=1

        #add adding char's count
        dic[A[i+B-1]]+=1

        #if adding char's freq is 1, that means its new addition
        if dic[A[i+B-1]]==1 and B>1:
            s+=1

        ls.append(s)

    return ls
```

It can be done in other ways but the concept remains same, this code is easier to understand .

Comment: Have you benchmarked this verses the OP's code? If so, how much faster is it?

Comment: I havent got the time to bench mark , but its faster I can say because, Its O(n) becasue its just looping once and doing O(1) work at every step for n times...
but in his solution everytime set building and length computation was done for n time, which makes it almost O(n^2) solution

Comment: @Socowi if you see carefully i am not calling the function at all, its a one time call for ist B chars, so its way faster, you can try in IDE.

Comment: if i had called `for i in dic.keys()` this in every condition, it would be same as his solution

Comment: Right its complete O(n) and can easily handle any range

Comment: right, @Socowi, I removed the `find` function, and replaced with the len(dic.keys()), thanks for the suggestion

Comment: `lambda: 0` could simply be `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Counter class to keep track of a sliding multiset. The count for each window would be the previous count +1 for adding a new value -1 for removing the last of an existing value:

```
from collections import Counter

def slidingDistinct(A,B):
    W      = Counter(A[:B])      # start out with the first window
    result = [len(W)]            # number of distinct key in initial counter 
    for rem,add in zip(A,A[B:]): # pair items to remove with the ones to add
        W[rem] -= 1              # remove item coming out of sliding window
        result.append(result[-1]+(W[add]==0)-(W[rem]==0)) # previous +1 / -1
        W[add] += 1              # add item coming into the window
    return result
```

Output:

```
print(slidingDistinct([1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3],3))
# [2, 3, 3, 2]
```

*This should be faster in cases where the window size is large and/or the variety of values is larger than the window size.*